# Grouping Notification in Notification Tray

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-notifications

In my app, I'm having **Push Notification**. When more than one notification received in my app means I need to show **2 Notification Received** **(Grouping)** but actually It Displaying Both notifications separately.

Comment: I haven't tried doing it myself so I can't help you in detail but I did read about there being a way to cancel a previously sent notification, you might want to look into that, see if you can cancel the previous one and send a new one with both details included.

Comment: You can't do it in client side, it can be managed from api service, the logic could be check time of last notification sent to an user if the notifications are within a limit the server can send a group notification instead of single notification.